# Is there any library for infinite canvas

Tags: layout, javafx

I'm searching for a javaFX layout that allows to place nodes on effectively infinite canvas, move items with drag-n-drop and have some means to navigate through the canvas.

Is there any available?

Comment: Not a canvas, but https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html + https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html

Comment: There is no need for pane actually, just group is enough.